# Numeric length validation

Tags: ibm-midrange, cobol

In a COBOL400 program I want to make a validation on a numeric field, on a screen, that when the entered number is less than 10, an error will occur.
The thing is when I enter some number e.g. `12345678`
the value will be placed like this in a numeric variable of 15 length
 
 `000000012345678`
so counting from the first number which is not 0 will not work all the time because of in case a 0 was entered from the user, e.g. `001234567`
Is there a way to do that without using a `FUNCTION` ?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking. The full list of Intrinsic Functions available to you are in your manual. However, why can't you just test it for being less than 10?

Comment: I need to check if the entered number is not less than 10 length, and I don't want to use the `FUNCTION` clause.

Comment: OK, that's clearer. FUNCTION isn't a clause. There isn't any single function in isolation which would do that for you anyway. So, yes you can do it without using a FUNCTION, because you can't do it by using a FUNCTION.

Comment: I'd suggest acquiring the data in a PIC X(10) field, and testing it for NUMERIC. There may be better solutions related to the specifics of Midrange and formatted screen displays, so I'll leave that to the Midrange guys who will be along.

Comment: okay thank you, can you give me a starter to the solution?

Comment: I don't know anything about how COBOL400 does its screens, so other than what I've already said (make the input alpha-numeric with a length of 10, and check it for being NUMERIC in your COBOL program) I can't suggest anything.

Comment: It could help us if we knew exactly what you need to do. Are you trying to verify that a value has exactly 10 digits? Or does it need to have **at least** 10 digits? Or is it something else?

Comment: Without a clear description of the problem, is this a homework or interview question? There should be no reason not to use a FUNCTION.

Comment: I think the problem is well described, kindly read it again with a cup of coffee.

Comment: It's not well-defined at all. It's actually self-contradictory. It asks about `validation on a numeric field, on a screen` and then asks about `in case a 0 was entered from the user`. But if it's a numeric field in a display file, you cannot tell if the user entered a leading zero or not. The leading zeros will be added automatically and your program is not notified how many characters are entered by the user. If it's a 10-digit field, your program sees 10 digits no matter how many are typed. It can't be a `numeric field` on the display; it needs to be a character field.

Comment: If your question were clear, we'd not be having such problems. Also, why do you want to store a telephone number as a numeric field? You going to do some calculation with it?

Comment: yes the problem is that I can't tell if the user entered leading zeroes I know that and that is my problem, so
The closest solution I came up to is to check if the numeric value is bigger than `1000000000`
if it is, then more than 10 digits are entered by the user, but in case of the first number of the phone is 0, then this won't work too.
I'm sorry if the question is not well-defined and thanks for the help.

Comment: @BillWoodger I have no clue why it is numeric, actually I think it is a good question to ask the analysis head for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code fragments to get you going.  If I understand the comment thread correctly, the user's response comes from a 10-character field, so it cannot be longer than that, but it might be shorter (the case that you want to block); and the user's response is moved into a 15-character numeric field in your program (RESPONSE-AS-NUMERIC).

```
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01  RESPONSE-AREA.
    05  RESPONSE-AS-NUMERIC              PIC 9(15).
    05  RESPONSE-AS-ALPHANUMERIC
        REDEFINES RESPONSE-AS-NUMERIC.
        10      FILLER                   PIC X(5).
        10  FIRST-DIGIT                  PIC X(1).
        10      FILLER                   PIC X(9).

* * * 

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
    MOVE SCREEN-FIELD TO RESPONSE-AS-NUMERIC
    IF FIRST-DIGIT = "0"
        reject the user's input
    END-IF
```

In short, you really only need to check the first digit.

Comment: Problem with that is, user can validly enter leading zeros.

Comment: I suppose so, now that I reread the question.  Like all the respondents, I don't fully understand the problem statement because the OP has not explained it clearly.

Comment: the idea is great actually, but what if the first digit of the number is 0 ? Knowing that the number represents a phone number, so as another possible solution i tested if the number is less than 100000000, if it is less, then it's not a 9 digits number. 9 digits to solve the case if the first number is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code which will allow you to determine if things are OK.

```
05  your-input-field.
    10  first-ten-digits-of-input          PIC 9(10).
    10  FILLER                             PIC X(5).
        88  no-more-than-10-digits         VALUE ZERO.

IF  ( first-ten-digits-of-input NUMERIC )
AND ( no-more-than-10-digits )
    user has entered exactly 10 numeric digts
ELSE
    user has misentered, it is too long, short, or not numeric
END-IF
```

Bear in mind, that I don't know how you have defined your field for "input", and I am not aware of the options that you have in defining your input. You must define the field as "character", not "numeric". If you define it as numeric, whatever is processing the input will, probably, right-justify (right-most digit in right-most position of field) and left-zero-pad. For a character field, it will be left-justified (left-most digit in left-most position of the field) and padded with trailing spaces to the field length.

However, if you are able to define an input field which can only contain numerics (and nothing else, no signs, decimal-points or anything) and that could be defined as left-justified, and such that it would be only 10 characters long, then you'd only need to test for NUMERIC, as everything else would be effectively done for you. But I don't know what you are using for input.

There is no FUNCTION is COBOL400 itself which you could usefully use to do this anyway.